# Question about scala.math.Integral

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

What do methods `mkNumericOps` and`mkOrderingOps` of [scala.math.Integral](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Integral.html) do and how can we use them?

I understand that functions and object methods can be declared `implicit` and used for implicit conversion. However I do not understand why *traits methods* are declared `implicit`.

BTW, can *class methods* be declared `implicit` too?

Comment: What do you mean by _trait methods_ and _class methods_? All methods are defined on a class or a trait, though some are defined on anonymous subclasses that in a seemless manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's see their declaration:

```
implicit def mkNumericOps (lhs: T): IntegralOps
implicit def mkOrderingOps (lhs: T): Ops
```

The fact that they are implicit means their goal is to provide some automatic value or conversion. Note that they both convert from `T` to some other type, where `T` is the type parameter of the trait: `Integral[T]`.

So, if you have `Integral[Int]`, then `mkNumericOps` will give you an automatic conversion from `Int` to `IntegralOps`. That means you'll be able to call methods from `IntegralOps` or `Ops` on an `Int` (or whatever it is the type of your `Integral`).

Now, let's see what methods are these:

```
def % (rhs: T): T
def * (rhs: T): T
def + (rhs: T): T
def - (rhs: T): T
def / (rhs: T): T
def /% (rhs: T): (T, T)
def abs (): T
def signum (): Int
def toDouble (): Double
def toFloat (): Float
def toInt (): Int
def toLong (): Long
def unary_- (): T
```

These are from `IntegralOps`, which extends `Ops`. An interesting thing about them is that many of them are already defined on `Int`! So, how and why one would use them? Here's an example:

```
def sum[T](list: List[T])(implicit integral: Integral[T]): T = {
    import integral._   // get the implicits in question into scope
    list.foldLeft(integral.zero)(_ + _)
}
```

So, given any type `T` for which there's an `Integral[T]` implicitly available, you can pass a list of that type to `sum`.

If, on the other hand, I made my method specific for the type `Int`, I could write it without `Integral`. On the other hand, I can't write something that will work for both `Int` and `Long` and `BigInt`, because they do not share a common ancestor defining the method `+` (much less a `zero´).

The `foldLeft` above is effectively translated as this:

```
list.foldLeft(integral.zero)((x, y) => mkNumericOps(x).+(y))
```