# Passing scala.math.Integral as implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I have read the answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506013/question-about-scala-math-integral) about [scala.math.Integral](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Integral.html) but I do not understand what happens when `Integral[T]` is passed as an implicit parameter. (I think I understand the implicit parameters concept in general).

Let's consider this function

```
import scala.math._

def foo[T](t: T)(implicit integral: Integral[T]) { println(integral) }
```

Now I call `foo` in REPL:

```
scala> foo(0)  
scala.math.Numeric$IntIsIntegral$@581ea2
scala> foo(0L)
scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral$@17fe89
```

How does the `integral` argument become `scala.math.Numeric$IntIsIntegral` and `scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The parameter is `implicit`, which means that the Scala compiler will look if it can find an implicit object somewhere that it can automatically fill in for the parameter.

When you pass in an `Int`, it's going to look for an implicit object that is an `Integral[Int]` and it finds it in `scala.math.Numeric`. You can look at the source code of `scala.math.Numeric`, where you will find this:

```
object Numeric {
  // ...

  trait IntIsIntegral extends Integral[Int] {
    // ...
  }

  // This is the implicit object that the compiler finds
  implicit object IntIsIntegral extends IntIsIntegral with Ordering.IntOrdering
}
```

Likewise, there is a different implicit object for `Long` that works the same way.

Comment: Thanks, now I think I get it. So, if `foo` is invoked with `Int` the compiler looks for an object, which extends `Implicit[Int]` and finds it in `scala.math.Numeric`.

Comment: @Misha exactly - in that case, your generic type parameter `T` will be filled in with the type `Int`, so it's going to look for an implicit `Integral[Int]` object. And if you call it with a `Long`, it's going to look for an implicit `Integral[Long]` object.

Comment: @Jesper I guess it works this way for any trait passing as implicit parameter. The compiler looks for an object extending the trait. Is it true ?

Comment: @Misha There doesn't necessarily have to be a trait; just an implicit object is needed that equals or extends the type that fits the implicit parameter.

Comment: @Jesper I see. However if we pass a trait then the compiler will look for an object, which extends the trait. Right ?

Comment: @Misha pass a trait, where exactly? The compiler will look for an implicit object that has a type that matches the type of the implicit argument. Do you mean that for `t` you pass something that implements some trait `MyTrait`? Then the compiler will look for an `Integral[MyTrait]`. So, by defining implicit objects, you can control which types can be passed to your method `foo`.

Answer (score 31):

The short answer is that Scala finds `IntIsIntegral` and `LongIsIntegral` inside the object `Numeric`, which is the companion object of the class `Numeric`, which is a super class of `Integral`.

Read on for the long answer.

## Types of Implicits

Implicits in Scala refers to either a value that can be passed "automatically", so to speak, or a conversion from one type to another that is made automatically.

### Implicit Conversion

Speaking very briefly about the latter type, if one calls a method `m` on an object `o` of a class `C`, and that class does not support method `m`, then Scala will look for an implicit conversion from `C` to something that *does* support `m`. A simple example would be the method `map` on `String`:

```
"abc".map(_.toInt)
```

`String` does not support the method `map`, but `StringOps` does, and there's an implicit conversion from `String` to `StringOps` available (see `implicit def augmentString` on `Predef`).

### Implicit Parameters

The other kind of implicit is the implicit *parameter*. These are passed to method calls like any other parameter, but the compiler tries to fill them in automatically. If it can't, it will complain. One *can* pass these parameters explicitly, which is how one uses `breakOut`, for example (see question about `breakOut`, on a day you are feeling up for a challenge).

In this case, one has to declare the need for an implicit, such as the `foo` method declaration:

```
def foo[T](t: T)(implicit integral: Integral[T]) {println(integral)}
```

### View Bounds

There's one situation where an implicit is both an implicit conversion and an implicit parameter. For example:

```
def getIndex[T, CC](seq: CC, value: T)(implicit conv: CC => Seq[T]) = seq.indexOf(value)

getIndex("abc", 'a')
```

The method `getIndex` can receive any object, as long as there is an implicit conversion available from its class to `Seq[T]`. Because of that, I can pass a `String` to `getIndex`, and it will work.

Behind the scenes, the compile changes `seq.IndexOf(value)` to `conv(seq).indexOf(value)`.

This is so useful that there is a syntactic sugar to write them. Using this syntactic sugar, `getIndex` can be defined like this:

```
def getIndex[T, CC <% Seq[T]](seq: CC, value: T) = seq.indexOf(value)
```

This syntactic sugar is described as a *view bound*, akin to an *upper bound* (`CC <: Seq[Int]`) or a *lower bound* (`T >: Null`).

Please be aware that [view bounds are deprecated from 2.11](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909), you should avoid them.

### Context Bounds

Another common pattern in implicit parameters is the *type class pattern*. This pattern enables the provision of common interfaces to classes which did not declare them. It can both serve as a bridge pattern -- gaining separation of concerns -- and as an adapter pattern.

The `Integral` class you mentioned is a classic example of type class pattern. Another example on Scala's standard library is `Ordering`. There's a library that makes heavy use of this pattern, called Scalaz.

This is an example of its use:

```
def sum[T](list: List[T])(implicit integral: Integral[T]): T = {
    import integral._   // get the implicits in question into scope
    list.foldLeft(integral.zero)(_ + _)
}
```

There is also a syntactic sugar for it, called a *context bound*, which is made less useful by the need to refer to the implicit. A straight conversion of that method looks like this:

```
def sum[T : Integral](list: List[T]): T = {
    val integral = implicitly[Integral[T]]
    import integral._   // get the implicits in question into scope
    list.foldLeft(integral.zero)(_ + _)
}
```

Context bounds are more useful when you just need to *pass* them to other methods that use them. For example, the method `sorted` on `Seq` needs an implicit `Ordering`. To create a method `reverseSort`, one could write:

```
def reverseSort[T : Ordering](seq: Seq[T]) = seq.reverse.sorted
```

Because `Ordering[T]` was implicitly passed to `reverseSort`, it can then pass it implicitly to `sorted`.

## Where do Implicits Come From?

When the compiler sees the need for an implicit, either because you are calling a method which does not exist on the object's class, or because you are calling a method that requires an implicit parameter, it will search for an implicit that will fit the need.

This search obey certain rules that define which implicits are visible and which are not. The following table showing where the compiler will search for implicits was taken from an excellent [presentation](http://suereth.blogspot.com/2011/02/slides-for-todays-nescala-talk.html) about implicits by Josh Suereth, which I heartily recommend to anyone wanting to improve their Scala knowledge.

1. First look in current scope

   1. Implicits defined in current scope
   2. Explicit imports
   3. wildcard imports
   4. Same scope in other files
2. Now look at associated types in

   1. Companion objects of a type
   2. Companion objects of type parameters types
   3. Outer objects for nested types
   4. Other dimensions

Let's give examples for them.

### Implicits Defined in Current Scope

```
implicit val n: Int = 5
def add(x: Int)(implicit y: Int) = x + y
add(5) // takes n from the current scope
```

### Explicit Imports

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap
def env = System.getenv() // Java map
val term = env("TERM")    // implicit conversion from Java Map to Scala Map
```

### Wildcard Imports

```
def sum[T : Integral](list: List[T]): T = {
    val integral = implicitly[Integral[T]]
    import integral._   // get the implicits in question into scope
    list.foldLeft(integral.zero)(_ + _)
}
```

### Same Scope in Other Files

This is like the first example, but assuming the implicit definition is in a different file than its usage. See also how [package objects](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4427) might be used in to bring in implicits.

### Companion Objects of a Type

There are two object companions of note here. First, the object companion of the "source" type is looked into. For instance, inside the object `Option` there is an implicit conversion to `Iterable`, so one can call `Iterable` methods on `Option`, or pass `Option` to something expecting an `Iterable`. For example:

```
for {
    x <- List(1, 2, 3)
    y <- Some('x')
} yield, (x, y)
```

That expression is translated by the compile into

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(x => Some('x').map(y => (x, y)))
```

However, `List.flatMap` expects a `TraversableOnce`, which `Option` is not. The compiler then looks inside `Option`'s object companion and finds the conversion to `Iterable`, which is a `TraversableOnce`, making this expression correct.

Second, the companion object of the expected type:

```
List(1, 2, 3).sorted
```

The method `sorted` takes an implicit `Ordering`. In this case, it looks inside the object `Ordering`, companion to the class `Ordering`, and finds an implicit `Ordering[Int]` there.

Note that companion objects of super classes are also looked into. For example:

```
class A(val n: Int)
object A { 
    implicit def str(a: A) = "A: %d" format a.n
}
class B(val x: Int, y: Int) extends A(y)
val b = new B(5, 2)
val s: String = b  // s == "A: 2"
```

This is how Scala found the implicit `Numeric[Int]` and `Numeric[Long]` in your question, by the way, as they are found inside `Numeric`, not `Integral`.

### Companion Objects of Type Parameters Types

This is required to make the type class pattern really work. Consider `Ordering`, for instance... it comes with some implicits in its companion object, but you can't add stuff to it. So how can you make an `Ordering` for your own class that is automatically found?

Let's start with the implementation:

```
class A(val n: Int)
object A {
    implicit val ord = new Ordering[A] {
        def compare(x: A, y: A) = implicitly[Ordering[Int]].compare(x.n, y.n)
    }
}
```

So, consider what happens when you call

```
List(new A(5), new A(2)).sorted
```

As we saw, the method `sorted` expects an `Ordering[A]` (actually, it expects an `Ordering[B]`, where `B >: A`). There isn't any such thing inside `Ordering`, and there is no "source" type on which to look. Obviously, it is finding it inside `A`, which is a *type parameter* of `Ordering`.

This is also how various collection methods expecting `CanBuildFrom` work: the implicits are found inside companion objects to the type parameters of `CanBuildFrom`.

### Outer Objects for Nested Types

I haven't actually seen examples of this. I'd be grateful if someone could share one. The principle is simple:

```
class A(val n: Int) {
  class B(val m: Int) { require(m < n) }
}
object A {
  implicit def bToString(b: A#B) = "B: %d" format b.m
}
val a = new A(5)
val b = new a.B(3)
val s: String = b  // s == "B: 3"
```

### Other Dimensions

I'm pretty sure this was a joke. I hope. :-)

**EDIT**

Related questions of interest:

- [Context and view bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again/4467012)
- [Chaining implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I was not joking :( However now I understand this stuff better :)

Comment: @Misha I meant Josh Suereth being joking about implicits being found in "other dimensions".

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral "if one calls a method m on an object o of a class C, and that class does not support method m, then Scala will look for an implicit conversion from C to something that does support m", is this the only case for implicit conversion ? implicit conversions on assignment seems to be different .. implicit def doubleToInt(d:Double) = d.toInt; 
val x: Int = 42.0

Comment: @FUD True indeed. Type ascriptions can cause implicit conversions as well.