# Are implicit parameter values implicit values themselves?

Tags: scala, implicit

To paraphrase the title question, are implicit parameters to a function implicit values within the function's scope?

Here's a small test:

```
object ImplicitTest{

  case class Foo()

  def myOtherFun()(implicit myfoo: Foo) = {
    val grabImpFoo = implicitly[Foo]
    println(myfoo.toString + " from myOtherFun")
  }
}

import ImplicitTest._

class ImplicitTest {
  def myFun()(implicit myfoo: Foo) = {
    println(myfoo.toString)
    myOtherFun()
  }

}
```

Now run it:

```
  implicit val foo = Foo()
  val it = new ImplicitTest()
  it.myFun()
```

This seems to demonstrate to me that implicit parameters are themselves implicit since `myOtherFun` can find an implicit argument, which I did not believe was the case for some time! I suppose this has advantages and disadvantages, but I'm just here to learn the facts; I looked at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html (based on [Passing scala.math.Integral as implicit parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512397/passing-scala-math-integral-as-implicit-parameter)) and didn't see any mention of this fact, if I'm understanding things correctly.

Comment: What exactly is your question though?

Comment: The title, but to paraphrase, are implicit parameters to a function implicit values within the function's scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes implict params can be accessed by other functions with matching implicit types within scope

Taken from http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html

> The actual arguments that are eligible to be passed to an implicit parameter fall into two categories:
>
> - First, eligible are all identifiers x that can be accessed at the
>   point of the method call without a prefix and that denote an implicit
>   definition or an implicit parameter.
> - Second, eligible are also all
>   members of companion modules of the implicit parameter’s type that are
>   labeled implicit.

Comment: Ah i see  "that denote an implicit definition *or an implicit parameter*"; not sure I saw this previously, but even if I did, I probably glossed over it - thanks!.